# Hudson and Maven tests run twice

Tags: maven-2, hudson, maven

```
Parsing POMs
Discovered a new module be.howest:someproject someproject
```

It seems to find a new module on the first time I make a hudson job. Well, nothing really to worry, but it seems to execute everything twice, and I don't really know why. Another thing is: it gives this odd error (at least to me):

```
[WARNING] Removing: cobertura from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
[WARNING] Removing: findbugs from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
```

***To me this looks like it tried to execute twice, but why is escaping me.***
Also, it has a module under the build, which is something i'm not very familiar with, but I wouldn't bother too much (and consider it normal) if it didn't do my tests twice.

right now it is running two phases: `clean` and `test`. I changed it to `clean package`, because I included javadoc in the package lifecycle, but nothing has changed.

---

- **Hudson console log**: http://pastebin.com/2GRmc2yP
- **Pom.xml**: http://pastebin.com/HL9Qd821

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven will execute tests first without any instrumentation, then it will execute cobertura plugin that will instrument the classes and re-run all the tests. Thus, the tests will be executed twice.

Answer (score 3):

It is `cobertura` which makes the tests run the second time.